# Using InvokeMember on a nestedProperty in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, reflection

I want to use the InvokeMember method for proceed to an OrderBy on a List but it works fine on simple types (string, datetime, etc...) but it fails on nested types...

Here my code :

```
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property = typeof(myType).GetProperty(e.SortExpression);
gridView.DataSource = myList.OrderBy(item => typeof(myType).InvokeMember(property.Name, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, item, null));
gvOrders.DataBind();
```

And I need something like this :

```
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property = typeof(myType).GetProperty(e.SortExpression);
gridView.DataSource = myList.OrderBy(item => typeof(myType).InvokeMember(property.GetNestedProperty("something").Name, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, item, null));
gvOrders.DataBind();
```

All advices are welcome :)

Comment: There is no such thing as a nested property.  Do you mean a property on a nested type?  If so, you need a `Type` object representing that nested type (and an instance, unless the property is static)

Comment: Yes I had seen the `GetNestedTypes()` but here I need something that let me do something like `OrderBy(item => item.Property.NestedProperty` I don't know if you see what I mean... Let me know if you need more explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly you are trying to get a property which is not of type `myType`.

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        SomeBar = new Bar();
    }

    public class Bar
    {
        public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public Bar SomeBar { get; set; }
}
```

You'll need to use [`Type.GetNestedType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getnestedtype.aspx) or [`Type.GetNestedTypes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getnestedtypes.aspx) to extract the inner type.

```
var foo = new Foo();
foo.SomeBar.SomeProperty = "Hello";

var someProperty = typeof(Foo).GetNestedType("Bar").GetProperty("SomeProperty");

Console.WriteLine(someProperty.GetValue(foo.SomeBar));
```

Using your code:

```
PropertyInfo property = typeof(myType).GetNestedTypes()
                                      .First()
                                      .GetProperty(e.SortExpression);
```

Comment: It fails too, message error is `Sequence contains no elements` on the `typeof(myType).GetNestedTypes().First()`

Comment: That would mean your type does not contain any nested types or the nested type is `non-public` or `static`. Try specifying the [`BindingFlags`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/493t6h7t.aspx).

Comment: All right, I got it. But with a little cheat ^^ I added to my class some "display" properties as string, so I can sort on it now. Anyway, thanks for the help :)

Comment: I put you as a resolver because your solution works in another situation but not for me ;)